# phpunit --testsuite command does not work

Tags: phpunit

I am on Windows in some project directory (I will call this my "root" directory).  I run this:

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit.phar -c tests/phpunit.xml --testsuite "Suite"
```

command runs but ignores my "Suite" and gleefully reports "No tests executed!"

phpunit.xml contains:

```
   <phpunit
    bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
    >
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Suite">
            <directory>;./</directory>
            <file>ProductTest.php</file>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

I have no problem running this on Linux, but on Windows it does not run this suite. I tried changing directory from `;./` to `;\` to `tests`, to full directory path on Windows, but no luck.  It does not complain but does not run the tests either.

How to I fix it?

Comment: note:  I think full path now works ... somehow there is some weirdness however, can't yet figure it out

Answer (score 0):

`<directory>..\tests</directory>` worked for me